# Trigger jquery function on blur unless specific elements are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login form. When the inputs get focused the "forgotten password" and "remember me" elements get shown by adding a css class, when they blur, the elements are hidden again by removing the class "sho". I would like the elements to keep the class "`show`"if I click either one of them or the login link

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.login *').focus(showlogin);
    $('.login *').blur(hidelogin);
});


function showlogin(){
    $('.login .hidden').addClass("show");
}

function hidelogin(){
    $('.login .hidden').removeClass("show");
}
```

Html:

```
<form class="login">
  <input type="text"/>
  <input type="password"/>
  <a class="loginbutton" href="#">Log in</a>
  <br />
  <a class="hidden" href="#">Forgotten password</a>
  <label class="hidden"><input type="checkbox" /> Remember me</label>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if post your css code

Comment: The css is kind of irrelevant, It's the trigger I'm after, I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding to `blur`, bind to a click outside the login form.

Here's some code I have in my page that closes my login box when I click outside it, you can adapt it to your needs:

```
    $(document).mousedown(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest("#signin").length == 0) {
            $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
            $("fieldset#signin_menu").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is a great idea! How should I do this without making it trigger on every single click?

Comment: You don't. It triggers on every click, but there's no effect if the fields are already hidden. But if you want, you can use `unbind` to remove the event handler that calls your function. But then you have to add it back in the `showLogin` function.

Comment: I tried the selectors ´$('*').not('.login').click(hidelogin);´ and ´$('*:not(.login)').click(hidelogin);´ but it seems to trigger anyway... Not sure what I should do...

Comment: See the sample code I just posted. It doesn't match your needs exactly, but does something similar in my application. The basic idea of checking where the click occurred can be used.

Comment: I realize this is old, and I'm only providing problems and not solutions, but what if the "blur" event is not the result of a click? (One example is when the tab key is pressed, but there are plenty of other ways to blur a field without a mouse click.)